# How to create a RecyclerView with horizontal scroll? - Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, android-recyclerview, horizontal-scrolling, horizontalscrollview

set this
android:orientation="horizontal"
app:reverseLayout="true"
in the layout doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When setting your layout manager set it like so in your Activity.kt file:

```
mRecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, true);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    class HorizontalRecyclerViewActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_horizontal_recycler_view)

        val recyclerView = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recycler_view)
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false)
        recyclerView.adapter = YourAdapter()
    }
}
```

The **layoutManager** property of the **RecyclerView** to a **LinearLayoutManager** with its orientation set to **HORIZONTAL**. The third argument of the **LinearLayoutManager** constructor sets the reverse layout, in this case false, meaning that the items will be laid out from left to right.

Then, you set the **adapter** property of the **RecyclerView** to an instance of **YourAdapter**, which is a custom adapter that provides data to the **RecyclerView**.